# Intermittent ConnectionFailedError Between Google Cloud Workflows and Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-run, orchestration, google-workflows

**Issue Description:**

We have a workflow set up in Google Cloud Workflows that occasionally encounters a "ConnectionFailedError" during an HTTP POST call to our Cloud Run service. This issue occurs sporadically and not consistently, causing the workflow to fail before the end of the specified timeout duration (1800 seconds).

**Steps Taken:**

1. We have reviewed our network connectivity and confirmed that there are no firewall rules or networking configurations blocking communication between Google Cloud Workflows and Cloud Run.
2. We have verified the availability and correct URL of our Cloud Run service to ensure it is deployed and accessible.
3. Error handling has been implemented in our workflows to catch the "ConnectionFailedError" and attempt retries with a suitable retry strategy.
4. Timeout settings have been properly configured on both the Google Cloud Workflows and Cloud Run side.
5. We have checked for any concurrency limits, rate limits, and authentication/authorization issues that might be contributing to the connection failures.
6. Logging and monitoring have been implemented to capture relevant information about the connection failures.

**Request for Assistance:**

Despite our efforts, we have been unable to pinpoint the root cause of these intermittent "ConnectionFailedError" instances.

It would be great to hear back from the experienced guys and the product team on the matter.

Comment: Can you share "when" the error occurs? I mean, at the invocation (the HTTP call fail) or the invocation is done (your Cloud Run process the request) but it's when Cloud Workflow waits for the HTTP response that the connection fail occurs

Comment: Connection times out due to lack of permissions and/or networking access from Dataflow job. Make sure you have given [required roles](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/server-connection-failed-error-while-connecting-to-cloud-sql-sql-server-from-dataflow-000004292)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the errors is occuring just after the invocation is done, meaning my Cloud Run well receiveid the request and is processing it, but the Workflow seems to lost the connection suddenly.

Comment: Can you retry deploying the workflow?

Comment: @RoopaM thanks for the suggestion. our Deployment is done via Terraform, permission/authorization are well configured and this error concern in intermittence not only 1 workflow. It happens once per 2-3 days, we have more than 50 workflows that run once per our or once per day. So I don't think so redeploying/permissions and/or networking access  would fix our fail.

Comment: I believe your issue requires internal analysis, so feel free to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: Agree the issue is strange. If the step duration (the Cloud Run call) is bellow 1800s, it should not fail.

Comment: Very strange, I agree with you. I have already sent a support mail to Cloud Workflow mailing group. We also continue to debug on our side. Thank you @RoopaM and Guillaume for you support. I will keep up to date the feed if there is any new information.

Comment: Open a real support case. The mailing list is only a user group, with eng team, but not their priority and there is no follow up.

Comment: Workflows compiled after May will convert some ConnectionErrors to ConnectionFailedErrors. `ConnectionFailedError` is used to expand Cloud Workflows' HTTP retry coverage and is retried in both default_retry_predicate and default_retry_predicate_non_idempotent. (ConnectionError is retried only in default_retry_predicate).

We are aware that we've not updated the public docs to include ConnectionFailedError tag. We'll do it soon.

Comment: Our code deals with the "ConnectionError"  tag as mentioned in the reference page of http.post (https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/http/post). We need to update our code to deal with this new tag, but waiting for the public docs to be updated @google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflows compiled after May will convert some ConnectionErrors to ConnectionFailedErrors. ConnectionFailedError is used to expand Cloud Workflows' HTTP retry coverage and is retried in both default_retry_predicate and default_retry_predicate_non_idempotent. (ConnectionError is retried only in default_retry_predicate). We are aware that we've not updated the public docs to include ConnectionFailedError tag. We'll do it soon.
Our code deals with the "ConnectionError" tag as mentioned in the reference page of http.post (cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/http/post). We need to update our code to deal with this new tag, but waiting for the public docs to be updated by @google.